# Sample data after grouping it based on a column in spark dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a spark dataset which is of the format:

```
Id dataset


id1,[name1,name2,name3...name100]
id2,[name1,name2,name3,nam4....name100000]
id3,[name1,name2,name3.....name1000]
```

I want to get a random sample of 50% of total names for each id.
I know spark has a sample function .But can I pass percentage to it based on each row of my dataset .Count of names will be different for each row.

This is what I have tried :

```
    WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(functions.rand());

 idDataset.select(col("name"), functions.rank().over(window).alias("rank"))
                .filter(functions.col("rank") = .05 ).drop("rank");
```

The 0.05 here means that I need to get random samples of 50% of the total names for each Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the built-in [SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#filter).

You can use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) to assign to each name a [random](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#random) value between 0.0 and 1.0 and then [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) out all names that got a random number assgined larger then your threshold (0.5 in this example).

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

df.withColumn("sampled",
       expr("filter(transform(names, n -> (n, rand())), n -> n.col2 <= 0.5).n"))
  .show(false);
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|id |names                                     |sampled                     |
+---+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|id1|[name1, name2, name3, name4]              |[name3]                     |
|id2|[name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6]|[name1, name2, name5, name6]|
|id3|[name1, name2, name3]                     |[name1, name2]              |
+---+------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: hi @werner from the result the sampled data isn't half of the total names for each id. Can you check once

Comment: well, that's expected. Its a random sample with each element having a 50% chance to be in the result.

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'random'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 33


@werner wondering why it says so

Comment: strange. The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#random) say that `random` is available since Spark 1.5.0